# Turning three similar methods into one method

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I want to turn these three methods into one, but am unable to wrap my brain around it at this moment. Complicated by the fact that 1/3 requires a slightly different call. They're all similar enough, and I know there is a better way, but beyond my skill level right now. With one extra variable passed in (fetch, check, or process) I could turn it into one, how to do this eludes me.

If you were to refactor these into one method, how would you do it?

```
def fetch(subjects = current_subjects, queues = QUEUES)
  subjects.each do |s|
    queues.each { |x| fetch_results(x, s) } unless queue.nil?
  end
end

def check(subjects = current_subjects, queues = QUEUES)
  subjects.each do |s|
    queues.each { |x| check_results(s["#{x}_recent"]) } unless queue.nil?
  end
end

def process(subjects = current_subjects, queues = QUEUES)
  subjects.each do |s|
    queues.each { |x| process_results(s["#{x}_recent"]) } unless queue.nil?
  end
end
```

EDIT: One solution is close to what I was thinking earlier, but I didn't make it clear that I want to pass in the `what` as a smallish array, that might be expandable and can used to indicate whether to fetch, check, or process or any combination of those. So, essentially, I'm trying to loop through three things with one method:

- an action what: I.E., fetch, check, or process.
- any number of subjects.
- any number of queues, which is a constant at the moment.

Also, other solutions here:

http://refactormycode.com/codes/2002-three-into-one

Comment: side note: queue is a enumerable, so name it accordingly: _queues_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lucapette proposes a top-down solution (which I think it's pretty valid on most cases). However, @Tony correctly points out that methods may evolve and so it may be too rigid. The alternative solution is a bottom-up approach:

```
def iter_queues(subjects, queues)
  subjects.each do |subject|
    (queues || []).each { |queue| yield(queue, subject) }
  end
end

def fetch(subjects = current_subjects, queues = QUEUES)
  iter_queues(subjects, queues) { |q, s| fetch_results(q, s) }
end
```

Ditto for the other methods. BTW, that double `each` can also be written:

```
subjects.product(queues).each { ... }
```

Comment: Well great minds think alike :) but I think I like the double each better

Answer (score 1):

```
def execute(what, subjects = current_subjects, queue = QUEUES)
  subjects.each do |s|
    queue.each { |x| send("#{what}_results", s["#{x}_recent"] ) } unless queue.nil?
  end
end
```

is a way to do it. Of course, naming is up to you.

Comment: Similar to what I was thinking earlier, but didn't get as far. The first, 'fetch', requires a slightly different call, so I need to either change that or work around it I'm guessing, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I might do something like this:

```
def with(subjects,queues)
    subjects.each do |subject|      
        queues.each do |queue|
            yield subject, queue
        end
    end
end

with(my_subjects, my_queues){|s, q| fetch_results(q, s)}
```

Comment: well, my idea below ;-) note that `with` can also be written `subjects.product(queues).each(&block)`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to refactor them into a single function?  They are similar now, but what if they evolve later on and become different?  Each function has it's own purpose and should be left as individual functions.

Comment: An excellent point, but there is no sense in repeating unnecessarily. It could go either way.

Comment: DRY them up now to make the code simpler. If one or more of the processes changes later, then extract that then. No sense keeping poorly arranged code just in case of "what ifs".